# Remove drivers intalled from Additional Drivers section

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, jockey

Ubuntu 11.04 was working fine with my Nvidia GT550M graphic card. It has got all shadows, effects etc. But yesterday i noticed the "additional drivers" icon in notification area and installed it. But now after login it says "your graphic card does not support unity, log in to classic gnome". how can i uninstall the driver and roll back to default one?

Comment: My guess is you de-activated it, instead of activating it, or else it didn't get installed correctly, double check to see if it is the active driver.

Comment: It's activated but i think the proprietary drivers are problematic. I deactivated it and problem solved

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to deactivate it from the application "Additional drivers" found in your main menu under "System > Administration".

After you have deactivated the driver, you must restart your computer for the changes to take effect. Upon login after restart Unity should work again.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I assume would be to the driver in Ubuntu Software Center and un-install it from there.

Beside that you can do the same...

1. From within Synaptic but you need a package to search from;
2. From command-line (sudo apt-get remove {package}.

You can also open 'additional hardware drivers' and de-activate it (or choose another one from the list)